# how to create google chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

i want to make google chart based my mysql. in localhost everything ok. no error showing. and it work.

but when i try to upload to my server it showing nothing.

here my code:

```
    <script>
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Date', 'Master Posts'],
<?php
$views = $db->query("SELECT date, COUNT(id_master_post) FROM master_post GROUP BY DAY(date) ASC");
$views->execute();
while ($value2 = $views->fetch()) { 
echo "['".substr($value2['date'], 0, -9)."',".$value2['COUNT(id_master_post)']."],";
} ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Master Posts Created',
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Views'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  <body>
    <div id="Views" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; float: left;"></div>
  </body>
```

when i try to run `SELECT date, COUNT(id_master_post) FROM master_post GROUP BY DAY(date) ASC` stright in sql from phpmyadmin. give me some error.

> SELECT date, COUNT(id_master_post) FROM master_post GROUP BY DAY(date)
>   ASC LIMIT 0, 25 MySQL menyatakan: Dokumentasi
>
> '#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'piratefiles.master_post.date' which is
>   not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Can you show us an error message? Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: no error massages.

Comment: Please isolate where the code begins to fail.  Echo some strategically placed checkpoints.

Comment: if you look at the source code is there a fully populated datatable?

Comment: The sql query has `where month(date)` but no condition to that - so it will always be true - is that expected?

Comment: @RamRaider im delete it but still no working

Comment: Post the relevant portion of source code as RamRaider requested.  Use backticks on `date` column -> it is a keyword.

Comment: ok - so without `where month(date)` does the query actually return any data?

Comment: `$views = $db->query` and `$views->execute();` ?? I think the first ought to be `$views = $db->prepare()` if you are calling `execute()`

Comment: ...but it worked locally?

Comment: @mickmackusa yes it work in localhost, but not work in my server. i think the proplem is in `SELECT date, COUNT(idpv) ....` i try to run stright in sql phpmyadmin it give me error, but working in sql phpmyadmin local.

Comment: Do share the error with us.

Comment: @RamRaider with/without `Where` output is same.

Comment: Going to have to vote to close as offtopic Why isnt my code working, if you don't provide the necessary details.

Comment: @mickmackusa im edit my question, hope someone can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Selecting a Column not in Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023347/mysql-selecting-a-column-not-in-group-by)

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807570/mysql-5-0-12-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column is more informative for you.  There are many duplicates to find.  You could have spared RamRaider so much trouble if you would have brought the error to your initial post (in fact you may have avoided asking at all if you would have found the error message on your own and continued to research).

Comment: I suppose now you just need to apply the WHERE clause to target your desired year - month and GROUP BY date (not DAY(date)).

Comment: ...oh this is a DATETIME column isnt it?  So the hh:mm:ss won't group.

Comment: @mickmackusa i want to group count by day, so result will group in day, if im just using date it will count all of it, i want to showing data by day. so if im posting 20 data in that day it will record 1 data if im using day(date), but if im only using date it will record 20 data

Comment: can you add your table schema to the question as it is unclear what type of columns are in question here.  ie: is `date` a simple `date` column or `datetime` ?

Answer (score 1):

The use of `query` and `execute` consecutively was confusing and quite possibly wrong - the `execute` method is used to execute a prepared statement but you did not create such a prepared statement. I began just formatting your code so I could work through it to see if I could identify an error and ended up with the following which might, or might not, be of use. I put comments in to help a little.

```
<?php

    /* column headers for chart datatable */
    $payload=array( "['Date', 'Post']" );

    /* create sql and prepare statement */
    $sql='select `date`, count(`idpv`) as `count` from `pageview` group by day( `date` ) desc';
    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt ){
        /* execute sql statement */
        $result=$stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        /* If there are results, process recordset */
        if( $result && $stmt->num_rows > 0 ){

            /*  bind results */

            $stmt->bind_result( $date, $count );

            /* fetch recordset */
            while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {

                $date=substr( $date, 0, -9 );
                $payload[]="[ '$date', $count ]";

            }
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
        }       
    }
    $db->close();

    /* 
        if there were no results this will only have column headers for datatable 
        this will be used by javascript function
    */
    $srcdata='['.implode( ',', $payload ).']';
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google charts & mysqli</title>
        <!--

            assumed here that the required google api scripts have been loaded

        -->
        <script>
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( drawChart );

            function drawChart() {
                /* 
                    echo the source data as a javascript variable before using in datatable
                */
                var srcdata=<?php echo $srcdata; ?>

                if( srcdata.length > 1 ){
                    /* 
                        There are more than just headers in src data array
                        so add to datatable and create chart
                    */
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable( srcdata );

                    var options = {
                      title: 'Page Views'
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( document.getElementById('Views') );
                    chart.draw( data, options );
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Views" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; float: left;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Tested demo, based upon a rudimentary emulation of your `pageview` table with some random example data inserted.

```
mysql> describe pageview;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| date  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| idpv  | mediumint(9) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and a snippet of the dummy data

```
mysql> select * from pageview limit 10;
+---------------------+------+
| date                | idpv |
+---------------------+------+
| 2015-01-11 00:00:00 |   54 |
| 2015-01-17 00:00:00 |   55 |
| 2015-01-20 00:00:00 |  121 |
| 2015-02-07 00:00:00 |   42 |
| 2015-03-08 00:00:00 |   57 |
| 2015-03-09 00:00:00 |  122 |
| 2015-04-01 00:00:00 |    5 |
| 2015-04-12 00:00:00 |   39 |
| 2015-04-19 00:00:00 |   98 |
| 2015-04-20 00:00:00 |   90 |
+---------------------+------+
```

-

```
<?php

    include __DIR__ . '/db.php'; #pertinent to my system!


    /* column headers for chart datatable */
    $payload=array( "['Date', 'Post']" );

    /* create sql and prepare statement */
    $sql='select 
            `date`, 
            count(`idpv`) as `count` 
            from `pageview` 
            group by day( `date` )
            order by date( `date` ) desc';

    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
    if( $stmt ){
        /* execute sql statement */
        $result=$stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        /* If there are results, process recordset */
        if( $result && $stmt->num_rows > 0 ){

            /* store and bind results */

            $stmt->bind_result( $date, $count );

            /* fetch recordset */
            while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
                $payload[]="[ '$date', $count ]";
            }
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
        }       
    }
    $db->close();

    /* 
        if there were no results this will only have column headers for datatable 
        this will be used by javascript function
    */
    $srcdata='['.implode( ',', $payload ).']';

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google charts & mysqli</title>
        <!--

            assumed here that the required google api scripts have been loaded

        -->
        <script src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
        <script>
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( drawChart );

            function drawChart() {
                /* 
                    echo the source data as a javascript variable before using in datatable
                */
                var srcdata=<?php echo $srcdata; ?>

                if( srcdata.length > 1 ){
                    /* 
                        There are more than just headers in src data array
                        so add to datatable and create chart
                    */
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable( srcdata );

                    var options = {
                      title: 'Page Views'
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( document.getElementById('Views') );
                    chart.draw( data, options );
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Views" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; float: left;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: See my last comment and please update your answer.  I can appreciate the time/care that you put in.  ...I might trim the date value in the SELECT rather than in php loop.

Comment: Good edit.  It must be datetime because of substr `-9`